# jQuery Event, callback and $(this)

Tags: jquery

I have a function that I use as a callback for a custom event:

```
function checkNCreateTb() {
        var tbName = $(this).attr('href').replace('content','orders')
        /*...*/
}
```

I used **.on()** to handle the event that will callback that function

```
$('#group-pills a').on('shown', checkNCreateTb)
```

I need to apply the same function the first time the user clicks a button in another part of the DOM. I solved it attaching a **click event** to the button and triggering the **shown event**. However, I think this looks very ugly, Is there a better way to get the same result?

**The code:**

```
$('button#action-button').on('click',function() {
    $('#group-pills a:first').trigger('shown')
    $(this).off('shown') //removing the handler
})

//Create the DataTable if it wasn't already created
$('#group-pills a').on('shown', checkNCreateTb)
```

Comment: "$(this).off('shown') //removing the handler" You remove the handler from $('button#action-button') but not from $('#group-pills a:first')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use [`$.proxy`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.proxy) to create a function reference with `this` set to a particular value:

```
$("#action-button").on("click", $.proxy(checkNCreateTb, $("#group-pills a:first")));
```

Or, alternatively, use [`call`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) to set the value of `this` in `checkNCreateTb`:

```
$('#action-button').on('click',function() {
    checkNCreateTb.call($("#group-pills a:first"));
});
```

As a side note, you do not need to prefix your `#id` selector with a tag name, since `id` is as specific as you can get and jQuery will use `document.getElementbyId` under the hood.

Comment: thanks Andrew. I used the event triggering approach because I didn't know how to change the **this** value. Also, thanks for the side note.